# TFS CI Build runs each unit tests twice

Tags: tfsbuild

We've a TFS Server with CI setup. Some reason, the CI runs each unit tests two times. Anyone got any hint why, please?

Comment: My crystal ball says: "....you have inadvertently told it to run tests twice...."

Comment: How do I tell it to run once? Which config do I manipulate?

Comment: Does it do 2 test runs or one run, but executing each test twice?

Answer (score 7):

This behavior may occur in the following combination:

- The test project is referenced by another project in the solution and
- MsBuild is instructed to generate folder for each project, i.e MsBuild switch `/p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true` is used

Answer (score 2):

Check your build definition. Here within the process details check your test sources. I would bet two of your filters are resolving to the same .dll causing this issue.

Comment: I had the same problem and this pointed me towards my solution. I only had one filter but it's recursive so for example if the dlls get copied again to a separate directory (oh say, for web deployment) it'll catch it twice. I made my filter not recursive and resolved.